# What does "inter-temporal evolution" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Today I read [a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/526257/319998) and I saw a phrase "inter-temporal evolution".

> A pre-trend analysis isn't a requirement, though it improves the
> credibility of a study. Typically, evaluators plot the outcome trends
> for the treatment group and the control group over time. We should
> expect the **inter-temporal evolution** of the trends to be reasonably
> parallel before the law/policy is enacted.
>
> For example, the authors in the paper you referenced plot the mean change in >asset growth in both groups in the 2 years before and the 5 years after the >adoption of a leniency law.

I am wondering what does it mean in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The prefix "inter" means "belonging to many" (think international = belonging to many nations). "Temporal" means "having to do with time or time frames".

In this situation, "inter-temporal evolution" refers to the  "mean change in asset growth in (..) the 2 years before and the 5 years after the adoption of a leniency law".

The two time frames are "2 years before" and "5 years after". They are looking at the difference in evolution between these two time frames.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the claim that ‘"inter" means "belonging to many"’?

Comment: @Void, I don't but I find it's the most useful definition for this instance.

Comment: @Void: OED **inter-** prefix, defn 1c: *‘Belonging in common to, or composed of elements derived from, **different things** (of the kind indicated by the second element)’*. It's perfectly reasonable to extrapolate ***many*** from ***different*** there.

Answer (score 0):

*Temporal evolution* is **time evolution**.

*Temporal* means **relating to time**.

*Inter* means **between**.

[*Inter-temporal*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intertemporal), thus, describes any relationship **between** past, present and future events or conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you quote

> We should expect the inter-temporal evolution of the trends to be reasonably parallel before the law/policy is enacted.

would be much improved by the omission of *inter-temporal* altogether. It is completely redundant since the trends referred to are changes over time. For much more detail about this form of analysis with some helpful graphs you might like look at the [Wikipedia article on difference in differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like jargon to me. Keep in mind that this term may have a specific meaning in the context of the field. Etymology of the phrase is also potentially useful as others have pointed out.